# Clangd is not found in VIM using neoclide / coc.nvim

Tags: vim, coc.nvim

1. I typed in Vim :CocInstall coc-clangd
2. Complains about clangd is not installed
3. sudo apt-get install clangd-10, also i installed clangd-9
4. still same error appears
5. reboot
6. still same error

[clangd is not found, you need to install clangd first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUZhf.png)

Is there something that I miss and you want to know guys?

Comment: You need `clang` installed in your system.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. `clangd-10` will be installed as `clangd-10`, try this: `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/clangd clangd /usr/bin/clangd-10 100`. https://clangd.llvm.org/installation.html
2. Make sure `clangd` can been found from `$PATH`, check: `which clangd` or `clangd --version`

```
❯ clangd --version
clangd version 10.0.0
```